# How to add a second legend using different `geom_line`?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am plotting the relationship between two variables (`X` and `Y`) for different individuals (`ID`s). This relationship is shown both with the real values (`geom_point`) and with lines which represent the prediction of the relationship between the variables for different individuals Linear Mixed Effect Models (LME). On top of that, the linear relationship between the two variables and for the different individuals is done using three levels of a second quantitative predictor (`Z`).

Thus, what I do is to use `geom_point()` for showing the relationship between raw values of `X` and `Y`. Then, I use three `geom_line()` for three LME with different levels of `Z`. Thus, each `geom_line()` draws the six lines for the six `ID`s for a fixed `Z`. So, since I have 3 `Z` levels and I have 3 `geom_line()`, I have 18 lines.

I tried this (note: code is simplified):

```
Plot_legend <- ggplot(df, aes(x=X, y=Y, colour=ID)) + 
  geom_point(size=1.5,alpha=0.2) +
  geom_line(aes(y=predict(model,df.Z_low), group=ID, linetype = c("1")), size=1.5, alpha=0.6, color = line_colors[3]) +
  geom_line(aes(y=predict(model,df.Z_medium), group=ID, linetype = c("2")), size=1.5, alpha=0.6, color = line_colors[2]) +
  geom_line(aes(y=predict(model,df.Z_high), group=ID, linetype = c("3")), size=1.5, alpha=0.6, color = line_colors[1]) +
  geom_abline(aes(slope=1,intercept=0),linetype="dashed",color="grey52",size=1.5) +
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(legend.text=element_text(size=18),
        legend.title = element_text(size=19, face = "bold",hjust = 0.5),
        legend.key=element_blank(),
        legend.background = element_rect(colour = 'black', fill = 'white', size = 1, linetype='solid')) +
  guides(color=guide_legend(override.aes=list(fill=NA)))
```

[image]

However, as you can see, the legend for the three `geom_line()` is not what I desire. I would like to appear as title `Z` instead of `c("10th")`. Also, the colours of the legend for the three `geom_line()` do not correspond with the true colours for the different `geom_line()`, and some lines are dashed.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

## Plot using Duck's advice

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach. As no data was shared I can test it but it can address in right path:

```
library(ggplot2)
#Code
Plot_legend <- ggplot(df, aes(x=X, y=Y, colour=ID)) + 
  geom_point(size=1.5,alpha=0.2) +
  geom_line(aes(y=predict(model,df.Z_low), group=ID, linetype = c("1")),
            size=1.5, alpha=0.6, color = line_colors[3]) +
  geom_line(aes(y=predict(model,df.Z_medium), group=ID, linetype = c("2")),
            size=1.5, alpha=0.6, color = line_colors[2]) +
  geom_line(aes(y=predict(model,df.Z_high), group=ID, linetype = c("3")),
            size=1.5, alpha=0.6, color = line_colors[1]) +
  geom_abline(aes(slope=1,intercept=0),linetype="dashed",color="grey52",size=1.5) +
  theme_bw() +
  scale_linetype_manual(values=c('solid','solid','solid'))+
  scale_color_manual(values=c(line_colors[3],line_colors[2],line_colors[1]))+
  labs(linetype='Z')
  theme(legend.text=element_text(size=18),
        legend.title = element_text(size=19, face = "bold",hjust = 0.5),
        legend.key=element_blank(),
        legend.background = element_rect(colour = 'black', fill = 'white', size = 1, linetype='solid')) +
  guides(color=guide_legend(override.aes=list(fill=NA)))
```

Comment: Thanks @Duck for your time. I get the next error message: "Error: Insufficient values in manual scale. 6 needed but only 3 provided". I wonder to which values it refers. There are 6 `ID`s, Does it refer to that? The sum of different `ID`s and geom_lines() is 9, not 6.

Comment: @Dekike Hi dear. It is not the sum, it is the color of the all lines in the plot. Can you try setting smt like this with arbitrary colors: `scale_color_manual(values=c('blue','pink','red','tomato','magenta','cyan3'))`? In case no working comment that line and check the other elements like linetype!

Comment: Ei, thanks! I tried what you said. I changed both `scale_color_manual()` and `scale_linetye_manual()` to get it work. In `scale_color_manual()` I used the colours you mentioned and in `scale_linetye_manual()` I repeated `solid` six times. I have checked that this change the colour of the points of my graph. I upload the plot in the post so you can see it. I am using as colour the `blue` in order you can see easily what the code does.

Comment: @Dekike I saw it, looks great, what else do you need to do?

Comment: No!! What I need is to change the colours of the legend with the lines! I mean, the colours for the legend should be the same colours that you see in the plot (red, blue and green). The colours are codified by `line_colors[1]`, etc. Do you understand? I do not want to change the colour of my points, they were OK. Different colours represent different `ID`s. I want to change the legend associated to `geom_line()` and thus, associated to the lines.

Comment: Ei!! I have got it using a different approach!!! I will share it here!! I don't know where was exactly the mistake...

Comment: @Dekike I saw, it looks great! Congrats!

Answer (score 1):

I used next code finally:

```
Plot_legend <- ggplot(df, aes(x=X, y=Y, colour=ID)) + 
  geom_point(size=1.5,alpha=0.2) +
  geom_abline(aes(slope=1,intercept=0),linetype="dashed",color="grey52",size=1.5) +
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(legend.text=element_text(size=18),
        legend.title = element_text(size=19, face = "bold",hjust = 0.5),
        legend.key=element_blank(),
        legend.background = element_rect(colour = 'black', fill = 'white', size = 1, linetype='solid')) +
  guides(color=guide_legend(override.aes=list(fill=NA)))

Plot_legend

Plot_legend_2 <- Plot_legend +
  geom_line(aes(y=predict(model,df.Z_low), group=ID, linetype = "m1"), size=1.5, alpha=0.6, color = line_colors[3]) +
  geom_line(aes(y=predict(model,df.Z_medium), group=ID, linetype ="m2"), size=1.5, alpha=0.6, color = line_colors[2]) +
  geom_line(aes(y=predict(model,df.Z_high), group=ID, linetype ="m3"), size=1.5, alpha=0.6, color = line_colors[1]) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c(m1 = "solid", m2 = "solid", m3 = "solid"),labels = c(m1 = "1", m2 = "2", m3 = "3")) +
  labs(color = "ID", linetype = expression(Z)) +
  guides(linetype = guide_legend(override.aes = list(color = line_colors)))

Plot_legend_2
```

[image]